# JQUERY show and hide not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which shows and hides content, the problem is when i click "Show More" it open up all the other sections instead of that specific section I clicked on and same thing with "Show Less"

Here is my code and [fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8y1dp5ej/2/)

[fiddle Demo 2](https://jsfiddle.net/8y1dp5ej/6/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("h4.showMore").on("click",function() {      $(this).parent().find(".hideResult").addClass("showResult").removeClass("hideResult");
      $(this).parent().find(".showMore").css("display", "none");
      $(this).parent().find(".showLess").css("display", "block");
});

$("h4.showLess").on("click",function() {

     $(this).parent().find(".showResult").removeClass("showResult").addClass("hideResult"); 
      $(this).parent().find(".showMore").css("display", "block");
      $(this).parent().find(".showLess").css("display", "none");
   }); 
});
```

Comment: They all have the same parent: `<div id="data">`. Wrap the sections in separate containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

demo:  https://jsfiddle.net/8y1dp5ej/3/

put separating `div` around each section

```
jsonVals += '<div class="newSection">';  // ADDED THIS
// the rest of the code with all the information
jsonVals += '</div>'; // ADDED THIS
```

then use `.closest()` function to find which `show more` or `show less` buttons belong to which section

```
$("h4.showMore").on("click",function() {
    $(this).closest('.newSection').find(".hideResult").addClass("showResult").removeClass("hideResult");
    $(this).closest('.newSection').find(".showMore").css("display", "none");
    $(this).closest('.newSection').find(".showLess").css("display", "block");
});
```